# Java could not find main class HelloWorld - ColdFusion interferes?

Tags: java

I am new to java (a real novice).

I installed Java 1.7.0 in the following folder

```
    C:\Program Files\Java
```

The environment variable which I set are

```
    PATH      : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin;
    JAVA_HOME : C:\Program Files\Java;
```

I have presented here the class names which are in my system. Next I wrote a simple HelloWorld program

```
    /*  HelloWorld.java */
    public class HelloWorld {
        public static void main(String args[]) {
           System.out.println("Hello, world carajo!");
        }
    }
```

I am able to compile successfully using `javac HelloWorld.java`. But when I try to run it with `java HelloWorld` I am encountering the below error:

> ```
>     Error: Could not find main class HelloWorld
> ```

The only way I could get this to work was using `java –cp . HelloWorld` . What I am doing wrong?

Also, I have ColdFusion installed and there is a system variable PATH set to the value below. Could this have anything to do with it?

```
C:\ColdFusion9\verity\k2\_nti40\bin;%CommonProgramFiles%\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;c:\Program Files\Common Files\Roxio Shared\DLLShared\;c:\Program Files\Common Files\Roxio Shared\10.0\DLLShared\;C:\Program Files\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files\Broadcom\Broadcom 802.11\Driver;C:\Program Files\QuickTime\QTSystem\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\binn\;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012a Student\bin
```

Answer (score 0):

set

`JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0`

Use below command.

`java -cp . (Your package.)HelloWorld`